# Pushing values in array in angularjs using array.push(val) creates deep copy or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

While using array.push() to add values at the end of an array in angularjs will it create a deep copy of the pushed value inside the array or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will be adding a *reference* to the original object to the array, not the value or a copy

```
var obj = { key: "value" }
var arr = [];
arr.push(obj);

obj === arr[0];
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Deep copy can be done via angular.copy. 
For example.

```
var data = [{'name':'abc'}, {'name':'xyz'}];
var copiedOne = angular.copy(data);
```

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript objects are **always** passed by reference unless you make a copy of it yourself.